# Java Springboot Restemplate response 500 while postman is not

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, org.json

I send a post with restTemplate, same params with postman but return 500 while postman is working, thanks for help so much. 
Example link:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-post-json

```
public void getRestTemplate(String user, String pass) {

    RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder = new RestTemplateBuilder();
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[]{MediaType.ALL}));
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());

    return restTemplateBuilder
            .messageConverters(converter)
            .basicAuthorization(user, pass)
            .setConnectTimeout(120000)
            .setReadTimeout(120000)
            .build();

}

public void abc() {
    String user = "...";
    String pass = "...";
    String url = "...";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate(user, pass);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray params = new JSONArray();
    params.put("a");
    params.put("b");
    params.put(false);
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    jsonObject.put("jsonrpc", "2.0");
    jsonObject.put("method", "x");
    jsonObject.put("params", params);
    jsonObject.put("id", 1);

    ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new
            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClients.createDefault());
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonObject.toString(), headers);
    String _response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, String.class);
}

/*
json format:
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "x",
    "params": [
        "a", "b", false
    ],
    "id": 1
}
*/
```

**Postman status 200**:

```
{
    "result": null,
    "error": null,
    "id": 1
}
```

Comment: Please post the console output and check parameter datatypes you are sending in postman.

Comment: @JawadHassanSoomro, same postman and java code params
{
 "method": "x",
 "id": 1,
 "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 "params": ["a", "b", false]
}
And here is result:
{"result":null,"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Top-level object parse error"},"id":null}.